# How can I represent different status' through colour coding?

Tags: excel

I want to change the colours of cells in a specific column when I enter "Y" in one of 3 other columns.

example: when I enter a "Y" in B3 the cell A3 turns red.

There is more, I want to create a whole table that has three columns each representing a form of communication. When a person requests to be contacted I can put a "Y" in one of the columns depending on the communication type.

When I put a "Y" in one of the three columns the cell in column A of the corresponding row turns red.

example: when a "Y" in one of any of the cells from B3-B33; C3-C33; D3-D33 the cells in for corresponding row from the A column turns red.

example: when a "Y" is placed in B30, A30 turns red; when a "Y" is placed in C7, A7 turns Red; If a "Y" is entered into D16, A16 turns red etc.

Then, I want the cell in the A column to turn yellow when an "X" is placed into the corresponding E column on the same row this is represented by the person have being contacted.

Then, I want the cell in column A to turn green, when the and "X" is place into the F column of the corresponding cell in Column A on the same row. This represents that the person has responded and dealt with.

I have tried work out excel code to make these conditions work but I am struggling. Any suggestions?

Comment: It looks like a typical case of conditional formatting, based on a formula.

Comment: I figured as much, I am just struggling to find the formula. I am new to this, so any advise would be helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional formatting in this order:

- First apply conditional formatting for Column F (check mark on "Stop if True")
- Second apply conditional formatting for Column E (check       mark on "Stop if True")
- Third Apply conditional formatting for       Column B,C & D

---

To add conditional formatting, follow these step:

Go to Home tab > Conditional formatting > New Rule

Select: Use a formula to determine which cells to format

- Input the formula shown in image
- Format the fill color per your requirement
- Click on Apply

To apply to the column A, you need to change applies to range using:

- Conditional Formatting > Manage Rules > Select the rule and change
  range address depending on your data size.

Please see this image:

[image]

The third condition is as under:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try it out now.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use conditional formatting? you can start off by doing a simple case.
In order to have multiple cases apply to the same cell you can access the  conditional formatting rules manager from the conditional formatting menu.

From there you can add additional rules for a cell.

For the formula itself i'd advise choosing: use a formula to determine which cells to format.
When the formula returns "true" the formatting will be used, so then you can make it search for all the row range you mentioned for the character you decide, you will need 1 rule for each color/character.
once you have done the formatting for one row you can drag it to apply it to all the rows if i remember correctly.

Comment: Firstly, thank you for your response.

I have done some formatting and code for setting up changing colours depending on number values. 

One of the things I am struggling with is creating an excel code for, changing the colours based on text. Like in my example above "Y" and "X" For example the one code I was trying is this: =IF(B3="Y",(A3="Not Blank", TRUE, FALSE),FALSE) and choosing the colour red.

I am new to this so feel a bit like this is over my head. Do you have any suggestion on the excel code I could use to make this happen. I also understand that the above formula is wrong.